# javascript: split string for multiple separators but also keep the separators as separate token

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to split a string but want to keep the token as well as the splitters as separate token and want an array to be returned:

```
elt(​a,b,c)" => 
0 = "elt"
1 = "("
2 = "a"
3 = ","
4 = "b"
5 = ","
6 = "c"
7 = ")"
```

here I am so far:

```
string = "elt(a, b, c)" 
string.split(new RegExp('[-+(),*/:? ]', 'g'))


0 = "elt"
1 = "a"
2 = ""
3 = "b"
4 = ""
5 = "c"
6 = ""
```

I want to pass the separators as an array like: `SEPERATORS = [ '+', ',', '>>>=', '>>=', '<<=',",", "("].join("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capture group in your regex to preseve the tokens:

```
string.split(/([-+(),*/:? ])/g)
              ^            ^
              |___ group __|
```

Output:

```
[
  'elt', '(', 'a', ',',
  '',    ' ', 'b', ',',
  '',    ' ', 'c', ')',
  ''
]
```

You can also easily remove the empty strings:

```
string.split(/([-+(),*/:? ])/g).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: what would happens if the seperators are multiple characters as an example, ">>>=" is the separator. I presume I can pass the separators as an array like `OPERATORS = ['>>>=', '>>=', '<<=',",", "("].join("")`

Comment: You can do it the same way, just don't use a character set in your regex, use `|` instead like `/(>>>=|>>=|<<=)/`

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting using lookarounds:

```js
var string = "elt(a, b, c)";
var parts = string.split(/(?<!\w)\s*(?=\w)|(?<=\w)\s*(?!\w)/);
console.log(parts);
```

The logic here is to consume any whitespace, and then split when what precedes the optional whitespace is either a non-word character, followed by a word character, or vice-versa.